# Display the rest of the table after the search Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to do a search with Selenium and display the results. Actually, I have a program in selenium to display a table and put a search word in the text field. And when the word is written automatically, tabulate the columns containing those words.

Here’s a code from my program.

```
private static String searchName = "//*[@id=\"searchName\"]";
private static String tableExist = "//table[@role='table']/tbody/tr";

//return if exist elements in the table
public static Boolean elementExistsInTheTableCustomer() {
    return (driver.findElements(By.xpath(tableExist)).size() > 0);
}
// here i put the text search
public static void enterSearchName(String nameSearchTxt) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(searchName)).sendKeys(nameSearchTxt);
}
// this function to put 2 char to search in the table
public static void searchStringName() {
    String strSearch = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(2);
    System.out.println("The String search : " + strSearch);
    Customer.enterSearchName(strSearch);
}
public static WebElement displayElementTables() {
    WebElement list =  webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(tableExist)));        
    return list;
} 

//here the test of element after and before the search name
@Test
public void GIVEN_Customers_On_Database() throws InterruptedException {
    Customer.clickCustomers();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if (Customer.elementExistsInTheTableCustomer()) {
        System.out.println("\t===============================");
        for (WebElement detail : Customer.displayElementTables()) {
            System.out.println("\t The elements in the table : " + detail.getText());
        }
        System.out.println("\t===============================");            
    }
    Customer.searchStringName();
    // here to display if i have elements or no 
    for (WebElement detail : Customer.displayElementTables()) {
            System.out.println("\t The elements in the table : " + detail.getText());
        }
}
```

In the last part, I will check if he has any lines to publish. the **displayElementTables()** function in which I can receive the search result. whether I have items or not and put the result in a variable to display.

Comment: why so many sysout ? use logger

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<WebElement> displayElementTables() {
    List<WebElement> list =  webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(tableExist)));        
    return list;
}
```